# Did Marconi steal and patent Jagadeesh Chandra Bose's wireless technology?

Tags: india, electronics, history-of-science

https://web.archive.org/web/20161026225031/http://indiainnings.in/108Facts/marconi

This is an excerpt from a books called `108 Facts eternally India`

> As early as 1885, J. C. Bose had demonstrated to the public of
>   Calcutta about his technology. He had blasted the gunpowder and made
>   the bell ring, which was one mile away from the place of
>   demonstration. "Wireless" communication era was born in Calcutta from
>   that moment. This demonstration had been reported in an international
>   Magazine called "Electrician" during that time. Important British
>   dignitaries also watched the J. C. Bose demonstrations at Calcutta.
>
> On September 21st 1896, J. C. Bose delivered a lecture cum
>   demonstration at Royal Institute, London on wireless transmission.
>   Eminent scientists including Marconi were present in that session.
>
> J. C. Bose, demonstrated before the scientist community at London, his
>   instruments, mainly the instrument called Co-Herer by using Mercury as
>   the conducting material and a telephone. Bose gave number of
>   demonstrations in Europe and America regarding wireless technology.
>
> In the year 1901, Marconi had patented the technology, used and
>   demonstrated by J. C. Bose and became its inventor and owner. Many
>   scientists had raised objections to this and asked Marconi about its
>   important part called "Co-Herer". He told the world community that a
>   friend called L. Solar gave it

1) Did Marconi really steal?

2) Did Jagadeesh Chandra Bose successfully transmit a wireless signal before Marconi

Comment: Marconi did not invent radio, but was the first one to use the technology in a commercially viable product. *Many* scientists worked and experienced with radio waves between 1880 and 1900. In 1901, Marconi had already succeeded with trans-atlantic transmissions of text messages. You can not compare that with 'ringing a bell a mile away', as performed by Bose in 1885.

Comment: Ditto Popov and Marconi

Answer (score 4):

Actually [The English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagadish_Chandra_Bose#Radio_research) has a great page about J. C. Bose.

> Bose went to London on a lecture tour in 1896 and met Italian inventor Guglielmo Marconi, who had been developing a radio wave wireless telegraphy system for over a year and was trying to market it to the British post service. In an interview, Bose expressed his disinterest in commercial telegraphy and suggested others use his research work.

Furthermore Marconi used ([from the Wikipedia page about Marconi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guglielmo_Marconi))

> The exact wavelength used is not known, but it is fairly reliably determined to have been in the neighbourhood of 350 meters (frequency ≈850 kHz)

While Bose focused on millimetre wavelengths.

The claim about stealing might be related to ["Sir J.C. Bose diode detector received Marconi's first transatlantic wireless signal of December 1901"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/658778/)

> Lieutenant L. Solari of the Royal Italian Navy, a childhood friend of G. Marconi's, experimented with this detector device and presented a trivially modified version to Marconi, who then applied for a British patent on the device